# Xampp Apache Not Starting After System Restart

Tags: apache

I have installed `xampp-1.8.3-4-VC11` in windows 7 ultimate and the issue is

first time after installing the `xampp` the **`apache`** is getting started and after pc proper shutdown / restart i am not able to start the apache again  check the below image for logs and i have also changed the apache port and remove all other apps which are running (inc of skype and anitviruse) but i am not able to start apache second time i search web a lot for this issue but i cant get rid for this can any one help in this .. ?
And i have also tried using the most latest version of xampp and the xampp 1.7.7 tooo... but no use... 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the xampp panel Open as you have kept it open.
Click on netstat .. there you will be able to see if any of the ports 80 & 443  are taken by any other processes.
If taken by any other process you need to kill that process using command prompt. Use this command -

Taskkill /PID [process id] /F

Example: taskkill /PID 1020 /F

Now try starting apache
IF tht doesn't work 
Click on the Explorer button in xampp control pannel . This will redirect you to the xampp folder where you have installed xampp ..  from there try to start apache as an administrator by right clicking on the apache_start.bat and then clicking Run as administrator from the menu.
This should definately work. If it still doesnt work do let me know and ill tell you a better solution..